# send multiple files from windows machine to a linux remote server "Jsch code"

Tags: java, scp, jsch

Could smoeone try to send multiple files to a remote server with Jsch, is this can be possible!!

I am trying to send a multiple of scripts perl to check some existing files and commandes in the remote server and after that a file which contains results must be returned in my local machine,the problem is that I have to use eclipse for that.

errors:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at /root/port.pl line 27, near "10.156.31.46 ssh"
    (Missing operator before ssh?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /root/port.pl line 27, near "8HcmdrGQDgXKL"
    (Missing operator before HcmdrGQDgXKL?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /root/port.pl line 27, near "9N1XgcLKUcC1DgFmcYoNLb1VsU9KYRhLAOGiIjWBdRkr6gLhZTJsnd2e464"
    (Missing operator before N1XgcLKUcC1DgFmcYoNLb1VsU9KYRhLAOGiIjWBdRkr6gLhZTJsnd2e464?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /root/port.pl line 27, near "2iIe3zJSlBH1tVd8PCifJaZ6Xu4KqsDFWjIILv8wY5XMWYdxVcPcMOsQhpl7vB2EgZxrc3yxE6rwfGnyxEKWez9W9t6e2hOvx3J21PxAGTaCIPjgxbcM4G"
    (Missing operator before iIe3zJSlBH1tVd8PCifJaZ6Xu4KqsDFWjIILv8wY5XMWYdxVcPcMOsQhpl7vB2EgZxrc3yxE6rwfGnyxEKWez9W9t6e2hOvx3J21PxAGTaCIPjgxbcM4G?)
syntax error at /root/port.pl line 27, near "10.156.31.46 ssh"
Execution of /root/port.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
exit-status: 255
```

this errors apears when I use FileOutput

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Computer\workspace\proj (Accès refusé)
```

Comment: Do you want to upload multiple files, or execute them, or both?

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Do you get exceptions? Does it do something else than what you want (if yes, what?).

Comment: it gives me this exception : `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException:0` and the cmd doesn't execute in the remote server

Comment: A bit more cooperation, please. In which line does this exception occur? My guess would be in `new FileInputStream(args[0])` - this only works if you call your program with the file name as a command line argument (the same argument is used as the host name, too). In your case, you would not need any input, since you uploaded the script - simply use `channel1.setInputStream(null)` instead.

Comment: the exception is gone but the commande dosn't execute in the remote server

Comment: Yeah, you are using `connect` and then immediately `disconnect()`. If the script needs longer than one network roundtrip, it will be canceled on the `disconnect()`.

Comment: You have to wait until the command finishes. Either by reading its output and waiting for the end, or simply do a timed waiting loop and wait for `getExitStatus()` to return something else than `-1`. Yeah, there is no *wait for finish* method, unfortunately.

Comment: Finally it works now !!! can I use that for dawnloading a file from the remote server `csftp2.get(fileAbsolutePath1, new FileInputStream(file1)); `

Comment: @Dark angel: What did you change? –  You will need a FileOutputStream instead of a FileInputStream to save something at the local side.

Comment: ok sorry I'll try it now thank you

Comment: ok, I'm dead it doesn't work also

Comment: Could you please post the complete code that you are using, and then add all error messages you get? I can only guess what you are doing here.

Comment: @Dark_angel: I added some help to my answer.

Comment: hi again!! I want to put this code in a method of actionperformed for a JButton !! this is can be possible !!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done rather simply.  You need to open a channel and simply put the binary object into the channel with the appropriate location.  If you want to do it with multiple files you can either do it sequentially or continuously submit to an Executor.

```
Session session = ...;// a new jSch Session with remote attributes (like ip, username and password)
Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
ChannelSftp csftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;

File file = new File(...); //binary file location to ftp
String fileAbsolutePath = ...;//The to location on remote server

csftp.put(new FileInputStream(file), fileAbsolutePath, file.length());
```

This is of course using jSch.  For more information you can check out this [example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java)

Comment: I tried this code but the commands didn't work!! maybe because the local machine OS is in windows and the remote server is in linux !!

Comment: That shouldn't be the case because I was able to do the same set of functions from Windows to OS.  Do you have any information on why it didnt work?  Did it fail to connect?  Did it get passed the .put without an exception?

Comment: Great, you're welcome!  What ended up being the problem is can others experience something similar?

Comment: There is a mistake in the use of the put method. The third argument is the transfer mode (RESUME, APPEND or OVERWRITE). See [ChannelSftp](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#put%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

I created  tutorials for jsch SCP Get and Put using java and Ant script.
[jsch tutorials](http://sshadmincontrol.com/documentation)

Answer (score 0):

You can only send one file at a time -- but perhaps you can use this in combination with a ZipInput/OutputStream and as such send multiple files this way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it is not easy. Sftp does allow sending mutiple files in one session. I do not know if scp uses one session or not when it sends multiple files.

I would recommend using the [ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) or using [apache camel](http://camel.apache.org/) to have a higher level, easy to use interface to deal with.

The ant task is a straightforward simple to use tool which does one job.

Camel on the other hand is a very flexible tools helping with all kind of problems when transferring information between different systems based on the Enterprise Integration Patterns. It offers also more features to make these transfers "industrial strength".

Comment: scp uses an `exec` channel, with a single stream used for all the files (and a confirmation between each, which makes it slow on low-latency connections).

Answer (score 0):

**Edited after the question was clarified.**

1. You need a [`ChannelSftp`](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/index.html?com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html), and use one (or more) of it's `put` methods. There is no problem in invoking them more than once, even concurrently (though this does not increase the bandwith, it might help for high-latency . (See John's answer for an example).
2. Then open a [`ChannelExec`](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/index.html?com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html) to execute your scripts. You can usually give multiple commands (separated by `;` or newlines) to the channel, it will pass them to the shell, which will execute them sequentially. Alternatively, use multiple channels here (one after another or concurrently).
3. After the last command finished, you use the [`ChannelSftp`](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/index.html?com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html) again to download the file (use a `get` method here).

This is not really related to Eclipse, other than maybe how to include the library in the build and run path (if so, state in a comment).

An alternative, if you do not really need to have the scripts as files on the server, would be to use a variant of the `perl` command which allows giving the script either on the command line (i.e. in the exec channels command string) or as standard input (i.e. in the exec channel's input stream). See the [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) documentation for details.
You could adapt your scripts that the result will not be written in a file, but produced as output (which you then can read from the exec channels output).

---

I added an [example](https://github.com/ePaul/jsch-documentation/blob/better-examples/examples/ExecLocalPerlScript.java) to my version of the JSch examples collection.

Here the important parts:

```
InputStream scriptStream =
  new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(arg[0]));

String command = "perl -w - ";

Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);


// input = script
channel.setInputStream(scriptStream);

// TODO: set other streams

channel.connect();
```

---

Okay, let's look at the errors.

First, you have some errors in your Perl script. It looks like wrong syntax in line 27. Have a look at this line, and if you don't find the problem, make a **new question** about this.

(You should first try to run this with a plain SSH connection, without JSch, to isolate the problems. Or better, first try to run it locally on your computer.)

Second, your FileNotFoundException (you should have used `e.printStackTrace()` instead of `System.out.println(e);` in the chatch block, by the way).

This `Accès refusé` means that your program has no right to write here. From your other paths, this is not a file name, but a directory name. You can't overwrite a directory with a file. Use the name your file should be saved under:

```
File file4 = new File("C:\\Users\\Computer\\workspace\\proj\\anime.txt");
```

Comment: "There is no problem in invoking them more than once."  That is meant sequentially, correct?

Comment: I meant sequentially, since I did not check whether they also work concurrently on the same Channel. If they don't, you can open multiple channels and upload them in parallel, although this still will not increase your overall bandwidth.

Comment: Multiple parallel Channels might be faster if you have lots of small files and high network latency. Of course, in such a case uploading a tar or zip file and unpacking it on the server will be even faster.

Comment: have plzz a little exemple which use ChannelExec

Comment: @Dark_angel: Here your example. Have fun!

Comment: If the question is solved, you can accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark icon below the vote count.